# qt и python: цикл for вывести в texEdit по нажатию кнопки

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, gui, pyqt

Есть цикл, нужно передать все значения цикла в `textEdit`. 
Проблема в том, что код передаёт только последнее значение в `textEdit`! ui ссылка на графическое окно!

```
a = 12
for i in range(5):
    a += 3
    print(a)
ui.textEdit.setText(a)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> QTextEdit::append(const QString &text)
>
> Добавляет новый абзац с текстом в конец редактирования текста.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QTextEdit,
                             QApplication, QWidget)

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
   
        self.textEdit = QTextEdit()
        self.btn = QPushButton("Запустить цикл")
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.on_button)
        
        self.main_layout = QVBoxLayout(self)        
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.textEdit)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.btn)
    
    def on_button(self):
        a = 12
        for i in range(5):
            a += 3
#            print(a)
#        ui.textEdit.setText(a)
            self.textEdit.append(str(a))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    a_window = Window()
    a_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо огромное) - не знаю чтоб без вас делал)

Comment: @AleksandrChirikov хорошего вам дня.